# I have to generate a table that has paragraphs, however, the text overflows the margins of the page

Tags: longtable, vertical, overflow

I have to generate a table that has paragraphs, however, the text overflows the margins of the page. I just need the text to break onto the next page.
I appreciate the help.

This the code I am using:

\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|p{6cm}|p{4cm}|}
\caption*{} \label{tab:long} \

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|p{5cm}|}{\textbf{Objetivo específico}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6cm}|}{\textbf{Metodología}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}|}{\textbf{Producto}} \ \hline
\endfirsthead

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|p{5cm}|}{\textbf{Objetivo específico}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6cm}|}{\textbf{Metodología}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}||}{\textbf{Producto}} \ \hline
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continua}} \ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

1. Hacía ya dos años que Brinco vivía en la vieja estación. Tan solo era un cachorro cuando vio por última vez a Tomé, su humano mejor amigo. Brinco no recordaba mucho de aquel día, solo que iban a subir en un tren con destino a algún lugar, cuando perdió de vista a Tomé. &

Hacía ya dos años que Brinco vivía en la vieja estación. Tan solo era un cachorro cuando vio por última vez a Tomé, su humano mejor amigo. Brinco no recordaba mucho de aquel día, solo que iban a subir en un tren con destino a algún lugar, cuando perdió de vista a Tomé. Y que, de pronto, a su alrededor todo eran piernas de gente que corría, apresurada. Brinco ladraba, llamando a Tomé. Pero sus ladridos quedaban ahogados por rugidos de trenes y silbatos de viejas locomotoras. El caos de prisa y ruido asustó mucho a Brinco, de manera que se refugió bajo un banco de piedra. Allí se quedó, temblando de miedo, hasta que llegó la noche y la estación quedó vacía. Todavía recordaba la visión, entre lágrimas, del tren haciéndose cada vez más pequeñito a medida que se alejaba.

Hacía ya dos años de aquél día. Y ni uno solo había dejado Brinco de esperar en la estación, por si Tomé volvía. Salía de debajo del banco que había convertido en su refugio, moviendo el rabo, cada vez que un nuevo tren llegaba a la estación. Pero Tomé nunca bajaba de ninguno de ellos. Entonces Madeja, una gata callejera que acudía cada día a la vieja estación en busca de restos de comida, se le acercaba en silencio.

-¿Tampoco ha habido suerte con este tren? -maulló la gatita.
-No, en este tampoco ha venido. Tal vez regrese mañana -respondió Brinco, aún lleno de optimismo.

Brinco estaba seguro que Tomé no se había olvidado de él. Y por eso esperaba en la vieja estación y acudía a recibir, esperanzado, a los pasajeros de cada tren que paraba.

Al principio fue duro. Brinco pasó mucho frío, tuvo que sobrevivir buscando comida en la basura. Algunos alimentos le provocaban dolor de tripa. Los días de lluvia, Brinco acababa empapado, y los guardias de la estación le perseguían para capturarlo y llevarlo a la perrera. Pero Brinco siempre lograba superar las adversidades: el deseo de reencontrarse con Tomé era mucho más fuerte. De modo que pronto los guardias se acostumbraron a él, y muchos pasajeros le cogieron cariño. Algunos de ellos le saludaban cuando bajaban del tren; otros, le ofrecían los restos de sus bocadillos. Y Brinco siempre guardaba un pedazo para su amiga Madeja.

-Ya han pasado dos años, Brinco. No va a volver. No sigas esperando -le aconsejó la gata.
-Pero entonces, ¿qué haré? ¿A dónde iré? Mi única ilusión es volver a estar con Tomé -respondió el perrito.
-No digo que renuncies a tu sueño, Brinco. Ve a buscarle. Deja de esperar que venga hasta ti y ve tú a su encuentro.
-Pero, Madeja, No sé a dónde nos dirigíamos. Ni siquiera pude ver qué tren cogió. ¿Por dónde podría empezar a buscar?
-No lo sé, Brinco. Pero aquí parece que no va a volver.

Aquella noche Brinco la pasó despierto, pensando en las palabras de su amiga Madeja. ¡La gata tenía razón! Si quería que algo cambiara, tenía que hacer algo diferente. De manera que, al amanecer, Brinco se coló en el vagón de carga del primer tren que paró en la vieja estación. ¡Buscaría por todas las ciudades, hasta en el último pueblo, si hacía falta! No renunciaría nunca a reencontrarse con Tomé.

---

Hacía ya dos años de aquél día. Y Tomé estaba triste. Había perdido a Brinco, su cachorrito, el día que cogió aquel tren en la vieja estación. No recordaba cómo pasó, sólo que Brinco caminaba a su lado y, de repente, ya no estaba. Buscó por todo el andén, chocando con cientos de personas que corrían, apresuradas. Llamándolo a voces. Pero sus gritos quedaban ahogados por rugidos de trenes y silbatos de viejas locomotoras. Tomé no quiso subir al tren, no quiso abandonar a Brinco. Pero sus tíos habían gastado todos sus ahorros en aquellos billetes y no tuvo otra opción que subir a bordo con ellos. Todavía recordaba la visión, entre lágrimas, de la vieja estación haciéndose cada vez más pequeñita a medida que el tren se alejaba.

Desde ese momento, Tomé había ahorrado cada céntimo para poder, algún día, comprar un billete de regreso a la vieja estación. ¡Y ese día había llegado!

-Perderás ese dinero y no lograrás nada. ¿Acaso crees que un perro espera dos años en una estación? -le advirtió su tía.
-Como no lograré nada es si no lo intento, tía.
-Tú verás. Pero no te hagas muchas ilusiones.

Tomé subió al primer tren del amanecer con la esperanza de reencontrarse con su amigo. El camino era largo. Aún así no le venció el cansancio. La ilusión por volver a abrazar a Brinco era mucho más fuerte.

Tomé viajaba mirando a través de la ventana. Le gustaba contemplar el paisaje.
Brinco viajaba en el espacio entre dos vagones. Le gustaba sentir el viento acariciando su hocico.

Y quiso el destino que ambos trenes se detuvieran en la misma estación. Y que los vagones de Tomé y de Brinco quedaran a la misma altura. Entonces se vieron.

-¡Paren el tren! ¡Paren el tren! ¡Es una emergencia! -gritó Tomé mientras se ponía en pie de un salto.

Tomé salió corriendo, atravesó el vagón de cuatro zancadas y saltó del tren justo cuando el jefe de estación tocaba el silbato para autorizar de nuevo la marcha.
Brinco también saltó al andén. Ambos se quedaron esperando a que marcharan los trenes, cada uno a un lado de las vías. Fueron unos segundos que parecieron una eternidad. Al fin, Brinco y Tomé pudieron reencontrarse.

-Mi querido Brinco. ¡Cuánto te he echado de menos! No nos separaremos nunca más -dijo Tomé, con lágrimas en los ojos.
-¿Ves cómo los sueños se cumplen? ¡Pero hay que perseguirlos! -se escuchó maullar a sus espaldas.
-¡Madeja! ¿Pero tú qué haces aquí? -se sorprendió Brinco.
-Crees que te habría dejado solo. Los amigos nunca se abandonan.
-Y tú… ¿ves cómo sí que iba a volver a buscarme? -hizo ver el perrito.
-Bueno, a veces el destino necesita que ambas partes den un paso adelante…

Desde ese día, Brinco y Tomé jamás se volvieron a separar; tampoco de Madeja, quien se fue a vivir con ellos a una bonita casa en el campo. Y los tres vivieron felices para siempre. Y nunca dejaron de perseguir sus sueños.
&
%Flujo de proceso
Hoja de cálculo de las pruebas funcionales realizadas por operación vinculadas con el procedimiento correspondiente, frecuencia de realización según lo indicado en el procedimiento y la cantidad de unidades requeridas. \newline
\newline
Frecuencia de las pruebas funcionales solicitadas por los planes de calidad correspondientes.

\ \hline

%---

2. Hacía ya dos años que Brinco vivía en la vieja estación. Tan solo era un cachorro cuando vio por última vez a Tomé, su humano mejor amigo. Brinco no recordaba mucho de aquel día, solo que iban a subir en un tren con destino a algún lugar, cuando perdió de vista a Tomé. &

Hacía ya dos años que Brinco vivía en la vieja estación. Tan solo era un cachorro cuando vio por última vez a Tomé, su humano mejor amigo. Brinco no recordaba mucho de aquel día, solo que iban a subir en un tren con destino a algún lugar, cuando perdió de vista a Tomé. Y que, de pronto, a su alrededor todo eran piernas de gente que corría, apresurada. Brinco ladraba, llamando a Tomé. Pero sus ladridos quedaban ahogados por rugidos de trenes y silbatos de viejas locomotoras. El caos de prisa y ruido asustó mucho a Brinco, de manera que se refugió bajo un banco de piedra. Allí se quedó, temblando de miedo, hasta que llegó la noche y la estación quedó vacía. Todavía recordaba la visión, entre lágrimas, del tren haciéndose cada vez más pequeñito a medida que se alejaba.

Hacía ya dos años de aquél día. Y ni uno solo había dejado Brinco de esperar en la estación, por si Tomé volvía. Salía de debajo del banco que había convertido en su refugio, moviendo el rabo, cada vez que un nuevo tren llegaba a la estación. Pero Tomé nunca bajaba de ninguno de ellos. Entonces Madeja, una gata callejera que acudía cada día a la vieja estación en busca de restos de comida, se le acercaba en silencio.

-¿Tampoco ha habido suerte con este tren? -maulló la gatita.
-No, en este tampoco ha venido. Tal vez regrese mañana -respondió Brinco, aún lleno de optimismo.

Brinco estaba seguro que Tomé no se había olvidado de él. Y por eso esperaba en la vieja estación y acudía a recibir, esperanzado, a los pasajeros de cada tren que paraba.

Al principio fue duro. Brinco pasó mucho frío, tuvo que sobrevivir buscando comida en la basura. Algunos alimentos le provocaban dolor de tripa. Los días de lluvia, Brinco acababa empapado, y los guardias de la estación le perseguían para capturarlo y llevarlo a la perrera. Pero Brinco siempre lograba superar las adversidades: el deseo de reencontrarse con Tomé era mucho más fuerte. De modo que pronto los guardias se acostumbraron a él, y muchos pasajeros le cogieron cariño. Algunos de ellos le saludaban cuando bajaban del tren; otros, le ofrecían los restos de sus bocadillos. Y Brinco siempre guardaba un pedazo para su amiga Madeja.

-Ya han pasado dos años, Brinco. No va a volver. No sigas esperando -le aconsejó la gata.
-Pero entonces, ¿qué haré? ¿A dónde iré? Mi única ilusión es volver a estar con Tomé -respondió el perrito.
-No digo que renuncies a tu sueño, Brinco. Ve a buscarle. Deja de esperar que venga hasta ti y ve tú a su encuentro.
-Pero, Madeja, No sé a dónde nos dirigíamos. Ni siquiera pude ver qué tren cogió. ¿Por dónde podría empezar a buscar?
-No lo sé, Brinco. Pero aquí parece que no va a volver.

Aquella noche Brinco la pasó despierto, pensando en las palabras de su amiga Madeja. ¡La gata tenía razón! Si quería que algo cambiara, tenía que hacer algo diferente. De manera que, al amanecer, Brinco se coló en el vagón de carga del primer tren que paró en la vieja estación. ¡Buscaría por todas las ciudades, hasta en el último pueblo, si hacía falta! No renunciaría nunca a reencontrarse con Tomé.

---

Hacía ya dos años de aquél día. Y Tomé estaba triste. Había perdido a Brinco, su cachorrito, el día que cogió aquel tren en la vieja estación. No recordaba cómo pasó, sólo que Brinco caminaba a su lado y, de repente, ya no estaba. Buscó por todo el andén, chocando con cientos de personas que corrían, apresuradas. Llamándolo a voces. Pero sus gritos quedaban ahogados por rugidos de trenes y silbatos de viejas locomotoras. Tomé no quiso subir al tren, no quiso abandonar a Brinco. Pero sus tíos habían gastado todos sus ahorros en aquellos billetes y no tuvo otra opción que subir a bordo con ellos. Todavía recordaba la visión, entre lágrimas, de la vieja estación haciéndose cada vez más pequeñita a medida que el tren se alejaba.

Desde ese momento, Tomé había ahorrado cada céntimo para poder, algún día, comprar un billete de regreso a la vieja estación. ¡Y ese día había llegado!

-Perderás ese dinero y no lograrás nada. ¿Acaso crees que un perro espera dos años en una estación? -le advirtió su tía.
-Como no lograré nada es si no lo intento, tía.
-Tú verás. Pero no te hagas muchas ilusiones.

Tomé subió al primer tren del amanecer con la esperanza de reencontrarse con su amigo. El camino era largo. Aún así no le venció el cansancio. La ilusión por volver a abrazar a Brinco era mucho más fuerte.

Tomé viajaba mirando a través de la ventana. Le gustaba contemplar el paisaje.
Brinco viajaba en el espacio entre dos vagones. Le gustaba sentir el viento acariciando su hocico.

Y quiso el destino que ambos trenes se detuvieran en la misma estación. Y que los vagones de Tomé y de Brinco quedaran a la misma altura. Entonces se vieron.

-¡Paren el tren! ¡Paren el tren! ¡Es una emergencia! -gritó Tomé mientras se ponía en pie de un salto.

Tomé salió corriendo, atravesó el vagón de cuatro zancadas y saltó del tren justo cuando el jefe de estación tocaba el silbato para autorizar de nuevo la marcha.
Brinco también saltó al andén. Ambos se quedaron esperando a que marcharan los trenes, cada uno a un lado de las vías. Fueron unos segundos que parecieron una eternidad. Al fin, Brinco y Tomé pudieron reencontrarse.

-Mi querido Brinco. ¡Cuánto te he echado de menos! No nos separaremos nunca más -dijo Tomé, con lágrimas en los ojos.
-¿Ves cómo los sueños se cumplen? ¡Pero hay que perseguirlos! -se escuchó maullar a sus espaldas.
-¡Madeja! ¿Pero tú qué haces aquí? -se sorprendió Brinco.
-Crees que te habría dejado solo. Los amigos nunca se abandonan.
-Y tú… ¿ves cómo sí que iba a volver a buscarme? -hizo ver el perrito.
-Bueno, a veces el destino necesita que ambas partes den un paso adelante…

Desde ese día, Brinco y Tomé jamás se volvieron a separar; tampoco de Madeja, quien se fue a vivir con ellos a una bonita casa en el campo. Y los tres vivieron felices para siempre. Y nunca dejaron de perseguir sus sueños. &

Pruebas funcionales que poseen discrepancias entre la practica, procedimiento y planes de calidad.\newline
\newline
Lista de personas que requieren entrenamientos.\newline
\newline
Hoja de entrenamientos para alineación de frecuencia de pruebas funcionales.

\ \hline

%---

3. Hacía ya dos años que Brinco vivía en la vieja estación. Tan solo era un cachorro cuando vio por última vez a Tomé, su humano mejor amigo. Brinco no recordaba mucho de aquel día, solo que iban a subir en un tren con destino a algún lugar, cuando perdió de vista a Tomé. &

Hacía ya dos años que Brinco vivía en la vieja estación. Tan solo era un cachorro cuando vio por última vez a Tomé, su humano mejor amigo. Brinco no recordaba mucho de aquel día, solo que iban a subir en un tren con destino a algún lugar, cuando perdió de vista a Tomé. Y que, de pronto, a su alrededor todo eran piernas de gente que corría, apresurada. Brinco ladraba, llamando a Tomé. Pero sus ladridos quedaban ahogados por rugidos de trenes y silbatos de viejas locomotoras. El caos de prisa y ruido asustó mucho a Brinco, de manera que se refugió bajo un banco de piedra. Allí se quedó, temblando de miedo, hasta que llegó la noche y la estación quedó vacía. Todavía recordaba la visión, entre lágrimas, del tren haciéndose cada vez más pequeñito a medida que se alejaba.

Hacía ya dos años de aquél día. Y ni uno solo había dejado Brinco de esperar en la estación, por si Tomé volvía. Salía de debajo del banco que había convertido en su refugio, moviendo el rabo, cada vez que un nuevo tren llegaba a la estación. Pero Tomé nunca bajaba de ninguno de ellos. Entonces Madeja, una gata callejera que acudía cada día a la vieja estación en busca de restos de comida, se le acercaba en silencio.

-¿Tampoco ha habido suerte con este tren? -maulló la gatita.
-No, en este tampoco ha venido. Tal vez regrese mañana -respondió Brinco, aún lleno de optimismo.

Brinco estaba seguro que Tomé no se había olvidado de él. Y por eso esperaba en la vieja estación y acudía a recibir, esperanzado, a los pasajeros de cada tren que paraba.

Al principio fue duro. Brinco pasó mucho frío, tuvo que sobrevivir buscando comida en la basura. Algunos alimentos le provocaban dolor de tripa. Los días de lluvia, Brinco acababa empapado, y los guardias de la estación le perseguían para capturarlo y llevarlo a la perrera. Pero Brinco siempre lograba superar las adversidades: el deseo de reencontrarse con Tomé era mucho más fuerte. De modo que pronto los guardias se acostumbraron a él, y muchos pasajeros le cogieron cariño. Algunos de ellos le saludaban cuando bajaban del tren; otros, le ofrecían los restos de sus bocadillos. Y Brinco siempre guardaba un pedazo para su amiga Madeja.

-Ya han pasado dos años, Brinco. No va a volver. No sigas esperando -le aconsejó la gata.
-Pero entonces, ¿qué haré? ¿A dónde iré? Mi única ilusión es volver a estar con Tomé -respondió el perrito.
-No digo que renuncies a tu sueño, Brinco. Ve a buscarle. Deja de esperar que venga hasta ti y ve tú a su encuentro.
-Pero, Madeja, No sé a dónde nos dirigíamos. Ni siquiera pude ver qué tren cogió. ¿Por dónde podría empezar a buscar?
-No lo sé, Brinco. Pero aquí parece que no va a volver.

Aquella noche Brinco la pasó despierto, pensando en las palabras de su amiga Madeja. ¡La gata tenía razón! Si quería que algo cambiara, tenía que hacer algo diferente. De manera que, al amanecer, Brinco se coló en el vagón de carga del primer tren que paró en la vieja estación. ¡Buscaría por todas las ciudades, hasta en el último pueblo, si hacía falta! No renunciaría nunca a reencontrarse con Tomé.

---

Hacía ya dos años de aquél día. Y Tomé estaba triste. Había perdido a Brinco, su cachorrito, el día que cogió aquel tren en la vieja estación. No recordaba cómo pasó, sólo que Brinco caminaba a su lado y, de repente, ya no estaba. Buscó por todo el andén, chocando con cientos de personas que corrían, apresuradas. Llamándolo a voces. Pero sus gritos quedaban ahogados por rugidos de trenes y silbatos de viejas locomotoras. Tomé no quiso subir al tren, no quiso abandonar a Brinco. Pero sus tíos habían gastado todos sus ahorros en aquellos billetes y no tuvo otra opción que subir a bordo con ellos. Todavía recordaba la visión, entre lágrimas, de la vieja estación haciéndose cada vez más pequeñita a medida que el tren se alejaba.

Desde ese momento, Tomé había ahorrado cada céntimo para poder, algún día, comprar un billete de regreso a la vieja estación. ¡Y ese día había llegado!

-Perderás ese dinero y no lograrás nada. ¿Acaso crees que un perro espera dos años en una estación? -le advirtió su tía.
-Como no lograré nada es si no lo intento, tía.
-Tú verás. Pero no te hagas muchas ilusiones.

Tomé subió al primer tren del amanecer con la esperanza de reencontrarse con su amigo. El camino era largo. Aún así no le venció el cansancio. La ilusión por volver a abrazar a Brinco era mucho más fuerte.

Tomé viajaba mirando a través de la ventana. Le gustaba contemplar el paisaje.
Brinco viajaba en el espacio entre dos vagones. Le gustaba sentir el viento acariciando su hocico.

Y quiso el destino que ambos trenes se detuvieran en la misma estación. Y que los vagones de Tomé y de Brinco quedaran a la misma altura. Entonces se vieron.

-¡Paren el tren! ¡Paren el tren! ¡Es una emergencia! -gritó Tomé mientras se ponía en pie de un salto.

Tomé salió corriendo, atravesó el vagón de cuatro zancadas y saltó del tren justo cuando el jefe de estación tocaba el silbato para autorizar de nuevo la marcha.
Brinco también saltó al andén. Ambos se quedaron esperando a que marcharan los trenes, cada uno a un lado de las vías. Fueron unos segundos que parecieron una eternidad. Al fin, Brinco y Tomé pudieron reencontrarse.

-Mi querido Brinco. ¡Cuánto te he echado de menos! No nos separaremos nunca más -dijo Tomé, con lágrimas en los ojos.
-¿Ves cómo los sueños se cumplen? ¡Pero hay que perseguirlos! -se escuchó maullar a sus espaldas.
-¡Madeja! ¿Pero tú qué haces aquí? -se sorprendió Brinco.
-Crees que te habría dejado solo. Los amigos nunca se abandonan.
-Y tú… ¿ves cómo sí que iba a volver a buscarme? -hizo ver el perrito.
-Bueno, a veces el destino necesita que ambas partes den un paso adelante…

Desde ese día, Brinco y Tomé jamás se volvieron a separar; tampoco de Madeja, quien se fue a vivir con ellos a una bonita casa en el campo. Y los tres vivieron felices para siempre. Y nunca dejaron de perseguir sus sueños.&

Tabla dinámica donde se presentan los números de lotes, fechas, operaciones y turnos de manufactura.\newline
\newline
Pronóstico de ahorro por familia de producción. \
\hline
\end{longtable}

This an example how long the text is in column 2. The table must be four rows (counting the header as one) and three columns.

Comment: Welcome! Can you complete your code so we can compile it?

Comment: In the case of something like `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`, TeX cannot break the line because this word doesn't fit the list of hyphenation patterns it has loaded. If you really need to break long non-words, you'll need to specify potential hyphenation points. In the case of the middle column, `longtable` will never break a cell. Page breaks are always inserted between cells. So you need to arrange your table with that in mind.

Comment: May I also ask what you are actually trying to do? Why do you think you need tables with cells containing this much text? I suspect this is an XY problem and there's a better way of typesetting whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Whatever else you do, *never, ever* encase a `longtable` environmen in a `center` environment.

Comment: In addition to all the above, `\begin{center}` doesn't take a `[ ]` argument.

Comment: The title of your query says, "I have to generate a table that has paragraphs." But 50+ [!] paragraphs, all confined to a single cell? A fundamental constraint of a `longtable` -- and of all tables, really -- is that the contents of a cell cannot be spread across two (or more) pages.

Comment: Hi cfr. In column one and three there some meaningful text but is shorter than the text in the second column. The random letters were just an example it really doesnt matter what would be in that columns because it wil fit. And I need this long text in the table because is the format that the university request. Thank you, for yor help I will edit the code for more clarity.

Comment: "The table must be four rows (counting the header as one) and three columns."  I'm still confused.  You have "1.", "2.", and "3." each with a line half way through.  Does that relate to the table needing 3 non-header rows?  If I add `\\ ` to break up your paragraphs to allow page breaks, then I end up with an 8 page 2nd column.  How should that fit into 3 non-header rows?  Do your columns need to have the widths you specify?  The easiest way to shorten your table is to widen the 2nd column and make the 1st and 3rd more narrow.  You still haven't shown us the contents of any of your columns.

Answer (score 3):

> I just need the text to break onto the next page.

The setup of your three-column table is a bit perplexing. There's nothing -- or, more precisely, *nothing meaningful*, in either column 1 or column 3, as I don't consider either

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

or

```
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

to be meaningful -- and about 50 [!] paragraphs of text in column 2, all in just one cell. This much text simply *cannot* fit in a single cell on a page.

As @cfr has already pointed in a comment, you should ask yourself if a table is the appropriate vehicle for displaying whatever it is that you wish to display. Tables should have not only several columns but also more than one data row. In contrast, your `longtable` has but one data row -- as well as, as already pointed out above, but one data column.

The following code simplifies and cleans up some of your code. Clearly, though, it *cannot* succeed in keeping the table from overflowing massively at the bottom of the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[textwidth=16.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{array,longtable}

\begin{document}

%\begin{center}[H] %% never, ever place a 'longtable' inside a 'center' env.
\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|p{6cm}|p{4cm}|}

\caption*{} \label{tab:long} \\
\hline 
\textbf{Objetivo específico} & 
\textbf{Metodología} & 
\textbf{Producto} \\ 
\hline 
\endfirsthead

\hline 
\textbf{Objetivo específico} & 
\textbf{Metodología} & 
\textbf{Producto} \\ 
\hline 
\endhead

\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{|r|}{Continua} \\ 
%\hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

1. %AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
& 
\obeylines % <-- just for this example
La estatua del Príncipe Feliz se alzaba sobre una alta columna, desde donde se dominaba toda la ciudad. Era dorada y estaba recubierta por finas láminas de oro; sus ojos eran dos brillantes zafiros y en el puño de la espada centelleaba un enorme rubí púrpura. El resplandor del oro y las piedras preciosas hacían que los habitantes de la ciudad admirasen al Príncipe Feliz más que a cualquier otra cosa.
—Es tan bonito como una veleta —comentaba uno de los regidores de la ciudad, a quien le interesaba ganar reputación de hombre de gustos artísticos—; claro que en realidad no es tan práctico —agregaba, porque al mismo tiempo temía que lo consideraran demasiado idealista, lo que por supuesto no era.
—¿Por qué no eres como el Príncipe Feliz —le decía una madre afligida a su pequeño hijo, que lloraba porque quería tener la luna—. El Príncipe Feliz no llora por nada.
—Mucho me consuela el ver que alguien en el mundo sea completamente feliz —murmuraba un hombre infortunado al contemplar la bella estatua.
—De verdad parece que fuese un ángel —comentaban entre ellos los niños del orfelinato al salir de la catedral, vestidos con brillantes capas rojas y albos delantalcitos.
—¿Y cómo saben qué aspecto tiene un ángel? —les refutaba el profesor de matemáticas— ¿Cuándo han visto un ángel?
—Los hemos visto, señor. ¡Claro que los hemos visto, en sueños! —le respondían los niños, y el profesor de matemáticas fruncía el ceño y adoptaba su aire más severo. Le parecía muy reprobable que los niños soñaran.
Una noche llegó volando a la ciudad una pequeña golondrina. Sus compañeras habían partido para Egipto seis semanas antes, pero ella se había quedado atrás, porque estaba enamorada de un junco, el más hermoso de todos los juncos de la orilla del río. Lo encontró a comienzos de la primavera, cuando revoloteaba sobre el río detrás de una gran mariposa amarilla, y el talle esbelto del junco la cautivó de tal manera, que se detuvo para meterle conversación.
—¿Puedo amarte? —le preguntó la golondrina, a quien no le gustaba andarse con rodeos.
El junco le hizo una amplia reverencia.
La golondrina entonces revoloteó alrededor, rozando el agua con las alas y trazando surcos de plata en la superficie. Era su manera de demostrar su amor. Y así pasó todo el verano.
—Es un ridículo enamoramiento —comentaban las demás golondrinas—; ese junco es desoladoramente hueco, no tiene un centavo y su familia es terriblemente numerosa—. Efectivamente toda la ribera del río estaba cubierta de juncos.
A la llegada del otoño, las demás golondrinas emprendieron el vuelo, y entonces la enamorada del junco se sintió muy sola y comenzó a cansarse de su amante.
—No dice nunca nada —se dijo—, y debe ser bastante infiel, porque siempre coquetea con la brisa.
Y realmente, cada vez que corría un poco de viento, el junco realizaba sus más graciosas reverencias.
—Además es demasiado sedentario —pensó también la golondrina—; y a mí me gusta viajar. Por eso el que me quiera debería también amar los viajes.
—¿Vas a venirte conmigo? —le preguntó al fin un día. Pero el junco se negó con la cabeza, le tenía mucho apego a su hogar.
—¡Eso quiere decir que sólo has estado jugando con mis sentimientos! —se quejó la golondrina—. Yo me voy a las pirámides de Egipto. ¡Adiós!
Y diciendo esto, se echó a volar.
Voló durante todo el día y, cuando ya caía la noche, llegó hasta la ciudad.
—¿Dónde podré dormir? —se preguntó—. Espero que en esta ciudad hay algún albergue donde pueda pernoctar.
En ese mismo instante descubrió la estatua del Príncipe Feliz sobre su columna.
—Voy a refugiarme ahí —se dijo—. El lugar es bonito y bien ventilado.
Y así diciendo, se posó entre los pies del Príncipe Feliz.
—Tengo una alcoba de oro —se dijo suavemente la golondrina mirando alrededor.
En seguida se preparó para dormir. Mas cuando aún no ponía la cabecita debajo de su ala, le cayó encima un grueso goterón.
—¡Qué cosa más curiosa! —exclamó—. No hay ni una nube en el cielo, las estrellas relucen claras y brillantes, y sin embargo llueve. En realidad este clima del norte de Europa es espantoso. Al junco le encantaba la lluvia, pero era de puro egoísta.
En ese mismo momento cayó otra gota.
—¿Pero para qué sirve este monumento si ni siquiera puede protegerme de la lluvia? —dijo—. Mejor voy a buscar una buena chimenea.
Y se preparó a levantar nuevamente el vuelo.
Sin embargo, antes de que alcanzara a abrir las alas, una tercera gota le cayó encima, y al mirar hacia arriba la golondrina vio... ¡Ah, lo que vio!
Los ojos del Príncipe Feliz estaban llenos de lágrimas, y las lágrimas le corrían por las áureas mejillas. Y tan bello se veía el rostro del Príncipe a la luz de la luna, que la golondrina se llenó de compasión.
—¿Quién eres? —preguntó.
—Soy el Príncipe Feliz.
—Pero si eres el Príncipe Feliz, ¿por qué lloras? Casi me has empapado.
—Cuando yo vivía, tenía un corazón humano —contesto la estatua—, pero no sabía lo que eran las lágrimas, porque vivía en la Mansión de la Despreocupación, donde no está permitida la entrada del dolor. Así, todos los días jugaba en el jardín con mis compañeros, y por las noches bailábamos en el gran salón. Alrededor del jardín del Palacio se elevaba un muro muy alto, pero nunca me dio curiosidad alguna por conocer lo que había más allá... ¡Era tan hermoso todo lo que me rodeaba! Mis cortesanos me decían el Príncipe Feliz, y de verdad era feliz, si es que el placer es lo mismo que la dicha. Viví así, y así morí. Y ahora que estoy muerto, me han puesto aquí arriba, tan alto que puedo ver toda la fealdad y toda la miseria de mi ciudad, y, aunque ahora mi corazón es de plomo, lo único que hago es llorar.
—¿Cómo? —se preguntó para sí la golondrina—, ¿no es oro de ley?
Era un avecita muy bien educada y jamás hacia comentarios en voz alta sobre la gente.
—Allá abajo —siguió hablando la estatua con voz baja y musical—... allá abajo, en una callejuela, hay una casa miserable, pero una de sus ventanas está abierta y dentro de la habitación hay una mujer sentada detrás de la mesa. Tiene el rostro demacrado y lleno de arrugas, y sus manos, ásperas y rojas, están acribilladas de pinchazos, porque es costurera. En este momento está bordando flores de la pasión en un traje de seda que vestirá la más hermosa de las damas de la reina en el próximo baile del Palacio. En un rincón de la habitación, acostado en la cama, está su hijito enfermo. El niño tiene fiebre y pide naranjas. Pero la mujer sólo puede darle agua del río, y el niño llora. Golondrina, golondrina, pequeña golondrina... ¡hazme un favor! Llévale a la mujer el rubí del puño de mi espada, ¿quieres? Yo no puedo moverme, ¿lo ves?... tengo los pies clavados en este pedestal.
—Los míos están esperándome en Egipto —contestó la golondrina—. Mis amigas ya deben estar revoloteando sobre el Nilo, y estarán charlando con los grandes lotos nubios. Y pronto irán a dormir a la tumba del gran Rey, donde se encuentra el propio faraón, en su ataúd pintado, envuelto en vendas amarillas, y embalsamado con especias olorosas. Alrededor del cuello lleva una cadena de jade verde, y sus manos son como hojas secas.
—Golondrina, golondrina, pequeña golondrina —dijo el Príncipe—, ¿por qué no te quedas una noche conmigo y eres mi mensajera? ¡El niño tiene tanta sed, y su madre, la costurera, está tan triste!
—Es que no me gustan mucho los niños —contesto— la golondrina—. El verano pasado, cuando estábamos viviendo a orillas del río, había dos muchachos, hijos del molinero, y eran tan mal educados que no se cansaban de tirarme piedras. ¡Claro que no acertaban nunca! Las golondrinas volamos demasiado bien, y además yo pertenezco a una familia célebre por su rapidez; pero, de todas maneras, era una impertinencia y una grosería.
Pero la mirada del Príncipe Feliz era tan triste, que finalmente la golondrina se enterneció.
—Ya está haciendo mucho frío —dijo—, pero me quedaré una noche contigo y seré tu mensajera.
—Gracias, golondrinita —dijo el Príncipe.
La golondrina arrancó entonces el gran rubí de la espada del Príncipe y, teniéndolo en el pico, voló por sobre los tejados. Pasó junto a la torre de la catedral, que tenía ángeles de mármol blanco. Pasó junto al Palacio, donde se oía música de baile y una hermosa muchacha salió al balcón con su pretendiente.
—¡Qué lindas son las estrellas —dijo el novio— y qué maravilloso es el poder del amor!
—Ojalá que mi traje esté listo para el baile de gala —contestó ella—. Mandé a bordar en la tela unas flores de la pasión. ¡Pero las costureras son tan flojas!
La golondrina voló sobre el río y vio las lámparas colgadas en los mástiles de los barcos. Pasó sobre el barrio de los judíos, donde vio a los viejos mercaderes hacer sus negocios y pesar monedas de oro en balanzas de cobre. Al fin llegó a la pobre casa, y se asomó por la ventana. El niño, en su cama, se agitaba de fiebre, y la madre se había dormido de cansancio. Entonces, la golondrina entró a la habitación y dejó el enorme rubí encima de la mesa, junto al dedal de la costurera. Después revoloteó dulcemente alrededor del niño enfermo, abanicándole la frente con las alas.
—¡Qué brisa tan deliciosa! —murmuró el niño—. Debo estar mejor.
Y se quedó dormido deslizándose en un sueño maravilloso.
Entonces la golondrina volvió hasta donde el Príncipe Feliz y le contó lo que había hecho.
&
%EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

\\ 
%\hline
\end{longtable}
%\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My guess is that each line should end with `\\ `, and start with `&`.  It also appears to be a story in the "Methodology" column, so I'm really not sure what OP is trying to do.